# What does hₖ[n] mean here?

Tags: lti-system

Is the impulse response different from the output y[n]? Is the input x[n] all the delta function at different values of n?

From *Signals and Systems* by Robert Oppenheim, Linear Time Invariant Systems:

[image: From Signals and Systems by Robert Oppenheim, Linear Time Invariant systems]

Answer (score 1):

\$h_k[n]\$ is the impulse response.

Output \$y[n]\$ is equal to \$h_k[n]\$ **if** the input \$x[n] = \delta_k[n]\$ (unit impulse shifted by \$k\$ samples).

In the general case where \$x[n]\neq\delta_k[n]\$, it can be represented as the sum of several time shifted impulses. \$x[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}{x[k] \delta_k[n]}\$.

To find the output, we have to take each value \$x[k]\$ in the input sequence, find its response \$x[k] \cdot h_k[n]\$ and add all the responses together to find the output (\$\sum_k(\cdot)\$). That addition is shown in equation (2.3)

\$h_k[n]\$ is the response of the system **if** the input was a single impulse shifted in time by \$k\$ samples. It is **an** impulse response.

It is the linearity property which allows us to split the input \$x[n]\$ into shifted impulses and later add the results back together to get the output.

The bottom left plot represents the input and bottom right plot represents the output. To get from input to output, we first split the input into impulses. That is shown on the top four, plots on the left. since they are impulses, and **if** we know the impulse responses, we get the top four plots on the right. They are impulse responses for the corresponding impulses. These are added to get the final response (valid because of the linearity property).

[image: illustrative diagram]

Comment: So hk[n] is the output to the system at that specific k, so it is essentially the output only, but at a time when delta(n-k) is 1. Does it mean I already know the output response ?

Comment: yes. Hkn is the output of the system if input was an impulse which had non zero value only at kth sample. But actual input may have non zero values for many samples. So the actual input is split into several impulses, each having a non zero value at a different sample.

Comment: "*Does it mean I already know the output response ?*". Yes. the paragraph you highlighted says that you already know the response to impulses with any amount of shift. You can use that knowledge to assemble responses to other types of inputs also, by splitting the input to impulses, and re assembling the impulse responses.